# Problem with sample names in the file created using awk

Tags: linux, bash, awk, filenames

I have some data like below:

```
dir1
  |___dir2
         |___dir3
               |____files
                      |____TGH4_1.tar.gz
                      |____TGH4_2.tar.gz
                      |____IOP5_1.tar.gz
                      |____IOP5_2.tar.gz
                      |____RGH2_btre_1.tar.gz
                      |____RGH2_btre_2.tar.gz
                      |____QWE6_btre_1.tar.gz
                      |____QWE6_btre_2.tar.gz
```

inside folder `dir3` I created a script `test.awk` which has code like below:

```
BEGIN {
    FS="[/_]"; OFS="\t"
    print "sample", "Second", "Third"
}
NR%2 { second = $0; next }
{ print $2, second, $0 }
```

Using the `test.awk` I created a file:

```
printf '%s\n' $PWD/files/* | awk -f test.awk > test.txt
```

The output `test.txt` I got is like below:

```
sample  Second  Third
dir1    /dir1/dir2/dir3/H0032/files/TGH4_1.tar.gz   /dir1/dir2/dir3/H0032/files/TGH4_2.tar.gz
dir1    /dir1/dir2/dir3/H0032/files/IOP5_1.tar.gz   /dir1/dir2/dir3/H0032/files/IOP5_2.tar.gz
dir1    /dir1/dir2/dir3/H0032/files/RGH2_btre_1.tar.gz  /dir1/dir2/dir3/H0032/files/RGH2_btre_2.tar.gz
dir1    /dir1/dir2/dir3/H0032/files/QWE6_btre_1.tar.gz  /dir1/dir2/dir3/H0032/files/QWE6_btre_2.tar.gz
```

The output should look like below:

```
sample  Second  Third
TGH4    /dir1/dir2/dir3/H0032/files/TGH4_1.tar.gz   /dir1/dir2/dir3/H0032/files/TGH4_2.tar.gz
IOP5    /dir1/dir2/dir3/H0032/files/IOP5_1.tar.gz   /dir1/dir2/dir3/H0032/files/IOP5_2.tar.gz
RGH2_btre   /dir1/dir2/dir3/H0032/files/RGH2_btre_1.tar.gz  /dir1/dir2/dir3/H0032/files/RGH2_btre_2.tar.gz
QWE6_btre   /dir1/dir2/dir3/H0032/files/QWE6_btre_1.tar.gz  /dir1/dir2/dir3/H0032/files/QWE6_btre_2.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
BEGIN { FS="[/_]" ... }
...
{ print $2, second, $0 }
```

to:

```
BEGIN { FS="/" ... }
...
{
    sample = $NF
    sub(/_[^_]*$/,"",sample)
    print sample, second, $0
}
```

Your code is printing `dir1` because that's the 2nd field of `/dir1/dir2/dir3/H0032/files/TGH4_2.tar.gz` given your FS setting and your code says `print $2...`.

Comment: Thank you very much again Ed Morton !!